# How can i parse this json correctly?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Right now i am trying to parse a complex json output from my api. Before using pagination it was fine (i will give the code below) but right now i am using pagination and i can't figure out how to parse this code.

**Json Output**

```
{
"count":6,
"next":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/articles/?format=json&limit=2&offset=2",
"previous":null,
"results":[{"id":"6463e530-368e-45c6-97ec-0599018a27df","email":"testuser1@gmail.com"}{"id":"7463e530-368e-45c6-97ec-0599018a27df","email":"testuser2@gmail.com"}]
}
```

Before pagination it was like this:

```
[{"id":"6463e530-368e-45c6-97ec-0599018a27df","email":"testuser1@gmail.com"},{"id":"7463e530-368e-45c6-97ec-0599018a27df","email":"testuser2@gmail.com"}]
```

What i need to do is parse the post model inside "results".
Here is my code

**Json Parse Code**

```
Future<List<Post>> FetchPosts(http.Client client,categoryconf) async {
  List<Post> posts;
  final response = await http.get("$SERVER_IP/api/articles/?format=json");
  final parsed = jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  posts = parsed.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromJSON(json)).toList();
  return posts;
}
```

Comment: Your sample json output is not an array, but in your code it seems like you  are expecting an array. Is your json an array of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how you fetch data.

```
class Pagination{
  int count;
  String next;
  String previous;
  List<Post> results;
  Pagination({this.count,this.next,this.previous,this.results});

  factory Pagination.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json,) {
    if (json["results"] != null) {
      var results= json["results"] as List;
      List<Post> _results=
      results.map((list) => Post.fromJson(list)).toList();
      return Pagination(
        results: _results,
        count: json["count"] as int,
        previous: json["previous"] as String
        next: json["next"] as String
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: oh damn,i never thought of that.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer, congrats!